Why is "I lack exercise" so uncommon? What are other ways to say "not get enough exercise"?
I'm doing some research on different ways to say "not get enough exercise", and it took me by great surprise how I seemingly can't say "lack exercise" or "short of exercise". I've used Youglish.com, Ludwig.guru, and Ngram to look for examples; there were very few of them showing up.
This made me realize how little I know about the verb lack and the phrase be short of. I always thought they could be used interchangeably with not have enough (of).
So, why is "I [lack/am in short of] physical exercise" so uncommon? What are other, preferably formal, ways to say "not get enough exercise" or "the fact that you don't get enough exercise"? Thank you!

There is no English expression be in short of. There's He is short of money and He is in need of money, but He is in short of money isn't valid. And we don't normally say He is in need of exercise or He is short of exercise. That might apply if he's a prisoner being denied the freedom to exercise, but normally we say He needs to exercise.

i.e. - He lacks exercise means he is prevented from exercising.

Thanks. I indeed mistook "be in short of" for "be short of". I've edited the question.

Is "prevented" a bit too strong? I mean doesn't I'm short of money/time simply mean you don't have enough of it? Is there anybody really preventing you from having more money?

"I don't get enough exercise." That's the way to express that thought. There isn't a more formal way to express it, since what you are saying is inherently imprecise. What exercise? What is enough? What criteria lead to such a self appraisal?

I specifically used prevented in the context of lacking exercise, not money. In the unlikely event that a native Anglophone said John lacks exercise, I would assume that's because he was denied the possibility of exercising. Not at all the same as John lacks common sense, for example. It all depends what one lacks, and why.

I think lack is typically used with a noun that describes something you could have or get. For example:

He lacks the experience to qualify for this job.
She lacks the ability to speak multiple languages.
They lack food.

Exercise is different because you can't really have or get exercise. It's something you do (that enables you to have or get something else).
If someone doesn't get enough exercise, you should simply say that the person doesn't get enough exercise or doesn't exercise enough. You could call the person lazy, but that would be a derogatory comment rather than an observation about exercise.
A similar example would be if someone is learning a new musical instrument and doesn't spend enough time practicing. That's similar to not getting enough exercise and you would simply say that the person doesn't get in enough practice, or doesn't practice enough.
Sometimes you can add a word such as "deprived", "impaired", or "challenged" to put a label on not having enough of something, but the word varies based on what they lack. For example:
Lacks sleep: sleep-deprived
Lacks sight: vision-impaired
Lacks hearing: hearing-impaired
Lacks height: vertically-challenged (an extreme example of how people try to be politically correct by using the word "challenged")
I don't think in short of is used very often. But you might say short on or short by to mean that you don't have enough of something:

I'm short on patience today.
It's the end of the month and I'm short on change.
I'm short by one donut.


Not very often? I don't think in short of is used ever. It's short on that's not used very often - usually you're short of whatever you don't have enough of.

Yeah, that was my mistake actually.
@swmcdonnell Thank you. I'd appreciate it if you could share your opinions on what type of noun following short of.

Idiomatically, it could be fine to say He lacks enthusiasm - usually, ... for . But He is short of enthusiasm is extremely unlikely.

Americans and Brits say I have no money equally often. But Americans don't use short of (or short on) anywhere near so often (that's why the preposition is "flexible" for them).

I disagree with @FumbleFingers and stand by my American English statement that I (and others) would say "I'm short on patience" and 'I'm short on change." and "I'm short by one donut." Short can also be a verb and someone can "short you," meaning they didn't give you enough of what they were supposed tyo give you.

I assume you didn't bother to check the link in my previous comment. It's true that short on money isn't quite so uncommon in AmE as it is in BrE, but short of money is overwhelmingly more common on both sides of the pond. I don't say there's anything wrong with the on version - just that it's far less common, everywhere.
